# EPPlus Calculate Extension Method not Calculating

Tags: c#, epplus

I'm exporting data to Excel using the EPPlus library, from a result in a DataTable.

I can't provide the exact cell address of the column I want to autosum because the number of rows in the DataSet will always vary due to a dynamic build, but the column(s) I want to apply the autosum to will always be in the same position.

I'm trying like this:

```
static async Task EPPlusExport(DataTable dataTable, FileInfo newFile)
    {
        try
        {
            using (ExcelPackage package = new ExcelPackage(newFile))
            {
                ExcelWorksheet workSheet = package.Workbook.Worksheets.Add("Raw Data");
                workSheet.Cells["A1"].LoadFromDataTable(dataTable, true);

                workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataTable.Columns.Count].Style.Fill.PatternType = OfficeOpenXml.Style.ExcelFillStyle.Solid;
                workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataTable.Columns.Count].Style.Fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.LightSlateGray);
                workSheet.Cells[1, 1, 1, dataTable.Columns.Count].AutoFilter = true;
                workSheet.View.FreezePanes(2, 1);
                workSheet.Cells[(dataTable.Rows.Count + 1), 22].Calculate();

                for (int i = 1; i < dataTable.Columns.Count; i++)
                {
                    workSheet.Column(i).AutoFit();
                }

                package.Save();
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
```

I assumed this will figure out which cell I want the autosum to be applied to:

```
workSheet.Cells[(dataTable.Rows.Count + 1), 22].Calculate();
```

I want the autosum on the row after the last row that contains data from my DataTable, and I want to sum column 22.  I can't hard-code the cell address.  Guess I'm going wrong somewhere?

I do use the await operator in this method. I just omitted unnecessary code for the purpose of the question :)

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The Calculate function will try to calculate any Excel formula in the cell you are referring to. It is not obvious in your code that the cell actually contains a formula. If not you need to add a SUM formula before you call Calculate.

```
workSheet.Cells[(dataTable.Rows.Count + 1), 22].Formula = "SUM(V1:V" + datatable.Rows.Count + ")";
workSheet.Cells[(dataTable.Rows.Count + 1), 22].Calculate();
```